# Efficient implementation of matrix operation in pytorch

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch

I would like to be able to write this more efficiently, ideally using vectorisation, is there a way to do it?

```
m = 100
n = 100
b = torch.rand(m)
a = torch.rand(m)
sumation = 0
A = torch.rand(n,n)
for i in range(m):
    sumation = sumation +  a[i]/(A - b[i]*torch.eye(n))
print(sumation)
```

I have tried this

```
# I have also tried something like this

torch.sum(torch.stack([a[i]/(A - b[i]*torch.eye(n)) for i in range(m)], dim=0), dim = 0)

# But this is a false assertation at some elements of the matrix output 
torch.sum(torch.stack([a[i]/(A - b[i]*torch.eye(n)) for i in range(m)], dim=0), dim = 0) == sumation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```py
m = 100
n = 100
b = torch.rand(m)
a = torch.rand(m)

B = torch.eye(n).unsqueeze(0) * b.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
A_minus_B = A.unsqueeze(0) - B
summation = torch.sum(a.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2) / A_minus_B, dim=0)
```

Note that due to numerics, the result won't be identical (ie `(summation_old == summation_new).all()` will be `False`), but `torch.allclose(summation_old, summation_new)` will return `True`.

Comment: Awesome, this is a great idea, thank you so much :)